# Different pronunciation of the suffix '-ege-': 'allege' vs 'renege'?

Tags: differences, pronunciation

1. What are some terms that relate to this phenomenon? I want to beware of similar cases.

2. What are the reasons?

Comment: It's not a suffix in either word. The base verbs are _lege_ and _nege_, the former from Old French (ultimately from Latin _litigāre_), the latter straight from Latin _nēgāre_. They're completely unrelated to each other, and the fact that they happen to contain the same three letters in their English form is just happenstance.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Would you like to recast your comment as an answer, for which I’ll happily upvote?

Comment: The real reason they're pronounced differently is that one came from Old French, after the pronunciation of *'g'* softened, and the other came straight from Latin, so its *'g'* is still hard.

Comment: @PeterShor, "renege" is the only example I'm aware of of an English word of Latin origin that doesn't follow the soft g pronunciation rule. Are there others?

Comment: How about [gibbous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gibbous)?

Comment: Highly related: [Why is “renege” pronounced with a hard “g” sound?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269879)

Answer (score 1):

I merely replicate Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment above:

> It's not a suffix in either word. The base verbs are *lege* and *nege*, the former from Old French (ultimately from Latin *litigāre*), the latter straight from Latin *nēgāre*. They're completely unrelated to each other, and the fact that they happen to contain the same three letters in their English form is just happenstance.

Comment: You probably should have allowed more than 5 minutes for him to post his own answer before you copied the comment yourself.