# Why is "renege" pronounced with a hard “g” sound?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The word *renege* comes from Medieval Latin *renegare* ([source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renege)). It is the only English word of Latin origin I'm aware of that doesn't follow the soft *g* pronunciation rule. The *g* is hard even though there's an *e* after it. Why?

Comment: Also [gibbous](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gibbous).

Comment: @PeterShor: *gibbous* is even more mysterious. The OED is stumped about why it's pronounced with /g/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s because it never had an affricate there. We spelled it *renegue* for some time, and some people still do. But just because we dropped the *u* for ease in spelling doesn’t mean we would change the sound.

The OED has:

> **renegue, renege** /rɪˈniːg/, /-ˈnɛg/, /-ˈneɪg/, *v.*
>
> Forms: 6–7, 9 reneague, 7–9 renegue, (6 ri-, 7 -neigue, 9 dial. -nague); 7, 9 reneg, (9 dial. -neeg); 6–7, 9– renege, 6–7 reneage, 9 dial. rena(i)ge, 8– U.S. renig.
>
> Etymology: ad. med.L. *reneg-āre*, f. *re-* re- + *negāre* to deny: cf. *renay* v.

As you see, it had all kinds of spellings since it was adopted into English, but would never have had the affricated pronunciation of *ju**dge***, only the stop of *fi**g***.

Comment: Compare *league* from the OED: ME leghe, ME–15 lege, leuge, (ME lewge, ME lewke, leuke, leeke), ME–15 leege, 15 legge, le(a)que, Sc. lig, 15–16 leag(e, 15– league. I think it's just change *renege* ended up with *-ge* and *league* didn't.

Comment: So much for my theory about King Lear II.2.73 the Folio has "revenge*, the Alexander Text edits to renege. Have you seen Ngrams: rare as hen's teeth until 1920 in the States (and arrives in UK forty years later). Must be all those card sharps they were writing about. And might be a back-formation from *renegado* to boot.

Comment: Maybe the real question should be:  Why didn't renege lose the e as well as the u?  Dialog/ue; Monolog/ue, Catalog/ue.

Comment: Thanks. The historical spellings explain a lot. I'm unfamiliar with the OED; what are all those numbers?

Comment: @SamKauffman The numbers before the historical forms represent the centuries of the second millennium, so 6–7 means during the sixteenth to the seventeen centuries (1501–1700).  However, a lone 1, which does not occur in this example, extends backwards in time indefinitely, so means  up through the eleventh century.

Comment: @tchirist: aren't all the numbers Middle English, which didn't start until a generation or so after 1066? The OED uses OE for Old English. So a 1 doesn't extend backwards indefinitely, just a decade or two before 1100.